# When using console.log, is it possible to hide the secondary body of text that outputs as VMxxxx:x(userscript.html) in the browser console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I usually need to copy the output and save to a file but I have to delete/replace the second body because it'll output for however many lines I'm asking for.

```
 myStuffData                           userscript.html?id=54de63cd-70fe-4251-a060-10bb80d193d8:32
```

Is there any way around this by outputting the text in a different manner? Here's the code I'm testing out.

```
function poo() {
    const myStuff = document.getElementsByClassName("itg gld");
    var elemCount = myStuff[0].childElementCount;
    myStuff[0].children.item(0).children[0];
    console.clear();
    for (let i = 0; i < elemCount; i+=1) {
    console.log (myStuff[0].children.item(i).children[0].href)}
}
```

Here's a picture of what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TxIP.png

Comment: What would you like to see instead of your current output? Is "myOutput" part of your output?

Comment: Yes. that gets shown as well as the text far beside it. i'd just like for just the myOutput text to be shown @LajosArpad

Comment: The edit that was added is conreecr. myOutput is the data contained in myStuff. The VM/userscript text is the also what appears at the right side of the console log

Comment: here's a picture of what i mean: https://i.imgur.com/6xGQofI.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. You can have a single output to pass to `console.log`, separating the lines with enter:

```
var myOutput = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) myOutput.push(i);
console.log("\n" + myOutput.join("\n"));
```

Comment: Thank you. I have much to learn. I was hoping that there would be a toggle setting for this but that wasn't the case. Much appreciated